# Adding custom html buttons to python highcharts in jupyter

Tags: python, highcharts, jupyter

I am trying to develop a highcharts plot, in jupyter, that updates the series values when a button is clicked.

#### A Dummy Example

Here is some dummy data for two separate charts. The xAxis and yAxis are the same. All I've done is reverse the order of the datapoints between the two charts.

**My goal** is to add a button that, when clicked, swaps out the series values between chart 1 and chart 2.

##### Chart One

```py
chart_one_dict = {
 'chart': {'type': 'column'},
 'plotOptions': {'column': {'stacking': 'percent'}},
 'series': [{'data': [50, 50, 50, 50], 'name': 'A'},
            {'data': [35, 35, 35, 35], 'name': 'B'},
            {'data': [15, 15, 15, 15], 'name': 'C'},
            {'data': [7, 7, 7, 7], 'name': 'D'},
            {'data': [3, 3, 3, 3], 'name': 'E'}],
 'title': {'align': 'left', 'text': 'Chart 1'},
 'xAxis': {'categories': ['05/21', '06/21', '07/21', '08/21']},
 'yAxis': {'min': 0,
           'stackLabels': {'enabled': 'true'},
           'title': {'text': 'Counts'}}
 }
options = HighchartsOptions.from_dict(chart_one_dict)
chart = Chart.from_options(options)
chart.display()
```

[image]

##### Chart Two

```py
chart_two_dict = {
 'chart': {'type': 'column'},
 'plotOptions': {'column': {'stacking': 'percent'}},
 'series': [{'data': [3, 3, 3, 3], 'name': 'A'},
            {'data': [7, 7, 7, 7], 'name': 'B'},
            {'data': [15, 15, 15, 15], 'name': 'C'},
            {'data': [35, 35, 35, 35], 'name': 'D'},
            {'data': [50, 50, 50, 50], 'name': 'E'}],
 'title': {'align': 'left', 'text': 'Chart 2'},
 'xAxis': {'categories': ['05/21', '06/21', '07/21', '08/21']},
 'yAxis': {'min': 0,
           'stackLabels': {'enabled': 'true'},
           'title': {'text': 'Counts'}}
 }
options = HighchartsOptions.from_dict(chart_two_dict)
chart = Chart.from_options(options)
chart.display()
```

[image]

#### Possible Solution?

In the highcharts-core documentation, a `Bindings` object ([Docs link](https://core-docs.highchartspython.com/en/latest/api/options/navigation/bindings.html#highcharts_core.options.navigation.bindings.Bindings)) is mentioned that appears to be for using custom HTML buttons, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Update: I have managed to add a button by subclassing Chart and adding a <button> tag to the output of the `_jupyter_container_html` method. I tried adding a <script> event listener to connect the button to the chart, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi @Joel - I'm Chris, the primary developer of the Highcharts for Python toolkit. This is an interesting use case - I haven't tried getting the `Bindings` configuration to work within a Jupyter context, so it's a good question. It is something that *should* work, and your approach of subclassing `Chart` and then inserting a custom button is a reasonable one. Now you would just need to configure the `Bindings` object (indicate the class name assigned to your button, etc.). Configuring `Bindings` may be a little more involved, though, so I'll test it out, write it up, & post it here as an answer